# javascript table column totalling

Tags: javascript

Being new to JavaScript I've been playing around on JSfiddle using the following html and javascript.
I can't seem to get the totals footer to populate, but what I'd really like to do is only total the last column, so that ultimately I can use a variation on the code in a project.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
    <thead>                
        <tr>
            <th>crop</th>
            <th>date1</th>
            <th>date2</th>
            <th>cropArea</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>barley</td>
        <td>01/01/2015</td>
        <td>01/01/2016</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>apples</td>
        <td>01/01/2016</td>
        <td>01/01/2017</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>corn</td>
        <td>01/12/2016</td>
        <td>05/05/2017</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>Total:</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table  th').each(function(i)
    {
        calculateColumn(i);
    });
});

function calculateColumn(index)
{
    var total = 0;
    $('table tr').each(function()
    {
        var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
        if (!isNaN(value))
       {
        total += value;
       }
    });

    $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
}​
```

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/6c63r14d/ Did you remember to include jQuery? If it doesn't work for you, do you see a JavaScript error in the console?

Comment: strange, it works if I follow the link you posted...

Comment: @Halcyon ya this must be the answer he was searching for.

Comment: Just a note. Always provide the `radix` parameter for `parseInt`. Since it can parse into different bases you probably don't want it shipping an Octal or Hexadecimal when you were looking for base 10.

Comment: so that's the totalling ok, any ideas around only totalling the last column and returning that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed JavaScript a bit so it works only **for the last column**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var sum = 0;
      $('table tr').each(function(el){
       var value = parseInt($(this).find('td:last').text());
        sum += value ? value : 0;
      })
      
      $('table tr:last td:last').html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
    <thead>                
        <tr>
            <th>crop</th>
            <th>date1</th>
            <th>date2</th>
            <th>cropArea</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>barley</td>
        <td>01/01/2015</td>
        <td>01/01/2016</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>apples</td>
        <td>01/01/2016</td>
        <td>01/01/2017</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>corn</td>
        <td>01/12/2016</td>
        <td>05/05/2017</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your logic for this by simply adding a class to the last column of each row. This will allow your javascript to only have to loop through the class and build the sum.

```js
var sum = 0;
var values = document.getElementsByClassName('last-col');
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 sum += parseInt(values[i].innerHTML);
}
document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;

/* jQuery */
/*$('.last-col').each(function() {
 sum += parseInt($(this).html());
});
$('#sum').html(sum);*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
    <thead>                
        <tr>
            <th>crop</th>
            <th>date1</th>
            <th>date2</th>
            <th>cropArea</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>barley</td>
        <td>01/01/2015</td>
        <td>01/01/2016</td>
        <td class="last-col">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>apples</td>
        <td>01/01/2016</td>
        <td>01/01/2017</td>
        <td class="last-col">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>corn</td>
        <td>01/12/2016</td>
        <td>05/05/2017</td>
        <td class="last-col">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td id="sum">Total:</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I like this approach and will use this in future, unfortunately I cannot change the existing table

Answer (score 1):

Put your data rows into a `<tbody>` to isolate them from `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows.

Then it is a simple loop over `tbody tr` and get last `td` on each of those

```js
$(function() {
  var lastColTotal = $('#sum_table tbody tr :last-child').get().reduce(function(sum, td) {
    return sum + (parseInt($(td).text(), 10) || 0)
  }, 0);

  $('#sum_table tfoot td:last').text('Total: ' + lastColTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>crop</th>
      <th>date1</th>
      <th>date2</th>
      <th>cropArea</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>barley</td>
      <td>01/01/2015</td>
      <td>01/01/2016</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>apples</td>
      <td>01/01/2016</td>
      <td>01/01/2017</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>corn</td>
      <td>01/12/2016</td>
      <td>05/05/2017</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```